# ingress-nginx whitelist-source-range and proxied ip's

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, whitelist, ingress-nginx

i'm running a grafana instance in kubernetes, which talks to a influxdb instance, also in kubernetes. both have their endpoints as Ingresses using ingress-nginx.

the issue is that when i use 'Server (default)' Access in grafana to define the Data Source, i would expect the requests to originate from the grafana server - which it does. however, the http headers contain:

```
X-Forwarded-For: 98.35.x.y, 127.0.0.1, 172.24.4.44, 172.24.4.44
X-Original-Forwarded-For: 98.35.x.y
X-Real-Ip: 98.35.x.y
```

to add a little more protection to my influx ingress i add:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "a.b.c.0/24,172.16.0.0/12"
```

now, the grafana instance is within the rfc1918 address range. however, it appears as though ingress-nginx is using one of the forwarded or x-real-ip headers against the whitelist - and subsequently returns a 403.

is there a way i can configure my influxdb ingress to allow my grafana proxied traffic through?

Comment: Could you please add which ingress version is used? Was it installed using helm or from manifest? Also, is there anything suspicious in ingress controller logs?